# Basic doubt in a free boundary problem for the Laplacian

Tags: elliptic-pde, laplacian, p-laplace, laplace-equation

I am studying the following article : http://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/docs/00/12/87/60/PDF/fbpLaplacian.pdf

In this article the authors considers $K \subset \{ x \in R^n  ; x_1 = 0 \}$ a smooth, bounded and convex set (when I say smooth I mean $C^\infty$).

The authors define $\mathcal{C} = \{ \Omega \subset R^{n}_+; \Omega \text{ is smooth, bounded, convex, and open such that } K \subset \partial \Omega \}$. Here $\mathbb{R}^n_+ = \{x = (x_1,...,x_n) \in \mathbb{R}^n ; x_1>0\}$.

For  $\Omega \in \mathcal{C}$  the problem

$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{cl}
\Delta u = 0  &\text{ in }  \Omega \text{ in the weak sense} \\
u = 1 &\text{ in } K \text{ in the trace sense} \\
u = 0 &\text{ on } \partial \Omega\setminus K \text{ in the trace sense} \\
\end{array}
\right.
$$

has a unique solution $u_{\Omega} \in H^{1}(\Omega)$. Now define the classes

$$ \mathcal{B} = \{ \Omega \in  \mathcal{C} ; \limsup_{y \rightarrow x} |\nabla u(y)| \leq 1 \quad \forall x \in \partial \Omega - K   \}$$

$$\mathcal{A}_0 = \{ \Omega \in  \mathcal{C} ; \limsup_{y \rightarrow x} |\nabla u(y)| > 1  \quad \forall x \in \partial \Omega - K   \} $$
(the classical gradient exists in $\Omega$ by regularity theory for the p-Laplacian).

In page five of the article the authors prove : if $\Omega_1 , \Omega_2 \in \mathcal{B} $ then $\Omega_1 \cap \Omega_2 \in \mathcal{B}$.

My **first question** is: Intersection of smooth domains is not smooth. Then when the authors says smooth, does he means piecewise smooth?

After this he states the following theorem: Let $(\Omega_n )$ be a decreasing sequence of convex domains of $\mathcal{B}$ such that

$$ \Omega = \text{int}(\overline{\cap \Omega_n}) \in \mathcal{C}.$$

Then $\Omega \in \mathcal{B}$.

After this he states and proves the following proposition:

Proposition: Assume that there exist two domains $\Omega_0 \in \mathcal{A}_0$ and $\Omega_1 \in \mathcal{B}$.  We denote by $\mathcal{S}$ the class of domains $D$ such that $\Omega_0 \subset D$ and $D \in \mathcal{B}$. Then there exists a minimal element in the class $\mathcal{S}$ for the inclusion.

In the proof of this proposition the author constructs a decreasing sequence $(\Omega_n) $ of bounded, convex , open and piecewise smooth domains (they are piecewise smooth because each element of this sequence is finite intersection  of smooth domains). After the construction the authors use the previous result for the sequence $(\Omega_n)$. Then they have to use that $\Omega = \text{int} (\overline{\cap \Omega_n})$ is smooth (or piecewise smooth depending of the meaning of smooth - I believe that it means piecewise smooth).

This proof raises the following question (I believe the author uses what I will ask):

**Question 2**: Is this claim true: Let $(\Omega_n)$ be a sequence of open, bounded, convex piecewise smooth domains such that $K \subset \partial \Omega_n $ ($K$ as in the beginning of this text). Then $\Omega = \text{int}(\overline{\cap \Omega_n})$ is piecewise smooth.

Can someone help me with these questions? Honestly I don't know the answers of my questions. Any commentary will be appreciated. Sorry for the long text and sorry for the English. My English is terrible...

Comment: why don't you contact the author, since you have questions about the precise meaning of his/her statements?

Comment: In your Question 2, $\Omega$ is the interior of something convex. What do you mean by it being piecewise smooth (every open subset is smooth), its boundary is piecewise smooth? Again, as in your other question, the claim about boundary is wrong. The presence of $K$ would barely help.

Comment: In the question you refer to p-Laplacian but in the equation you use the 2-Laplacian. Is that correct?

Comment: the correct is the 2- laplacian. sorry for my mistake. thanks for your commentary